# Displaying a list in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple list of strings, which I've bound to a gridview:

`List<string> directories = new List<string>();
    DirectoryGV.DataSource = directories;
    DirectoryGV.DataBind();`

I would like select buttons on the GV

How do I access the data of the list to populate the select buttons?

What is the DataField name?

`<asp:Button ID="ImportBtn" runat="server"
    CommandName="Import"
    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Item") %>'
    Text="'<%# "Import " + Eval("Item") %>" />`

Item isn't the right field name, but I can't find what is

Comment: I didn't quite understand...Do you want to get the value of the selected item or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Container.DataItem`

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>

                <%# Container.DataItem %>

                <asp:Button ID="ImportBtn" runat="server" CommandName="Import" 
                  CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItem %>' 
                  Text='<%# "Import " + Container.DataItem %>' />

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```